# passing rs.getString values between the jsp pages using hidden field

Tags: jsp

I want to pass rs.getString values from 1st.jsp to 2nd.jsp using hidden fields like

```
                   <input type="hidden" value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>" name="h">
```

and in the 2nd.jsp
                            String s=request.getParameter("h");

and print the string, but it prints null

Answer (score 0):

Check that is this hidden field inside form tag? make sure you have to set input type="**submit**" and  Also make sure the form action matches your @WebServlet definition or not.